# Setting Up new domain for WHM, ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: dns, web, hosting, cpanel, whm

I got WHM on our VPS and already set up some websites in it.

Usually, I only need to create new Account, fill out the form (domain name, setting, etc).
Then change the nameserver on the registrar's website, then wait for max 48 hours.
Then the website is live.

But now the **website is not live yet**. I have been contacting the hosting support, but they do not respond quick.

**Could you guys please let me know what should I check to identify the problem?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to check if you WHM hostname is a valid hostname and then if the hostname points back to the WHM server ip. Then you have to check with a tool like intodns.com if you DNS zone for the domain is correct and if the domain name points back to your server's ip. If you can, please post your domain name (the one that is supposed to load from your WHM server).